# Como obter dados do Jframe

Tags: java

Olá, ultimamente tenho a seguinte dúvida: como pegar um dado que foi gerado em um jframe e mandar para outra classe. A ideia é usar o jframe apenas para preencher e me retornar os valores que ali foi inserido para outra classe, que no caso seria a main, tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, o jframe nada mais é que uma classe, então poderias por exemplo no jframe que vai ser dado o retorno das informações criar variáveis que vão salvar essas informações para que na hora que ele se fechar voce possa obtelos por get's por exemplo... 
Exemplo>
Vamos fazer de conta que eu tenha um jframe ja aberto e vou abrir outro nesse exato momento que vai ser o cadastro de um cliente...
entao eu digo

```
Cadastro_Cliente cad = new Cadastro_Cliente();
cad.setvisible(true);
```

logo meu cad esta visivel, e preencherei tudo nele.
ao finalizalo eu salvei todas as informações em variáveis e também criei os getteres para eles.. como por exemplo:

```
public String getNome(){
return this.nome;
}
```

Logo depois desse form "cad" fechado com evento .dispose() eu posso acessar os valores que continham nas variáveis..
Exemplo:

```
if (cad.getNome()!=null){
system.out.println(cad.getNome());
}
```